# Do wildcard certificates support nested subdomains?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Supposed I create a certificate for `*.example.com`. Then this certificate of course matches `www.example.com` as well as `foo.example.com`. Basically everything under `example.com`.

But what about …

- `example.com` itself?
- `foo.bar.example.com`?

Are these matched as well by a wildcard certificate? If not - is there a way to do so?

As I've now learned you can use SANs to support `example.com`, and only a single level of subdomain matching is supported.

Does `*.*.example.com` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate):

Only a single level of subdomain matching is supported.

And example.com is not covered, only anything.example.com is. SubjectAlternativeName extension is usually used to cover example.com itself.

Comment: Besides Wikipedia, [RFC 6125](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#section-6.4.3) says that too, indeed.